# How do I create an engine loop in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm not quite sure if I'm overthinking this, or just approaching it the wrong way in node.

I want to have an object (in this specific case it will be a component tree) in memory that will be accessible to all sessions. I'd also like to have it update on some kind of "heartbeat" separate from user sessions.

Comment: you should not do this. having scalability in mind session data and shared memory should never live in memory. memory sessions limit your hablity to scale and are not al reliable, try something like Redis. How ever if you feel you must do this. you can add it to the global object or just have a module to export an object and then require it where ever you need to access the memory.

Comment: and what is the question? Are you asking how to achieve this ? You need to have a persistent storage for the object and that is not the memory heap. Distributed system with database replication and/or memory caching (Redis) can be a way to go. This way data is retrieve/created/updated once required.

Comment: How would I go about implementing  a loop similar to what a game loop would be? Just instead of processing frames I'd be updating the components in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

To have a object that is available to all sessions you need some storage outside the node.js process as the comments already mentioned. The natural choice would be [redis](http://redis.io/) because it is fast and also "speaks" JavaScript. This is the best way to share the data between processes.

To update the local copy of the data in the storage in a "heartbeat" like interval you can use [`setInterval`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg).

Comment: Just been doing more reading on this "issue", why would you suggest setInterval over setImmediate? Curious what the advantages of either are.

Comment: `setImmediate` only executes once after the event loop is finished. But you wanted to execute it again and again, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to emulate either a windows message loop, or a typical game loop. If setInterval gets me there then great.